# Trivial editing on my answer

Tags: discussion, edits, behavior

My answer was just edited twice in under 5 minutes, both were in my opinion trivial, unnecessary edits. One even went as far as to add the word "link" to a jsFiddle, which I can assume was simply to meet the 6 character minimum.

I know there are those that can't stand to see a misplaced comma,,,,  but aren't trivial edits intentionally discouraged to prevent gaming the system?

Should edits of fewer characters be allowed to prevent editors from adding noise to meet the minimum?

When you spot this behavior is there a proper recourse?

Here's the link as requested:
[AnimationEnd not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553344/animationend-not-working/16553572#16553572)

Comment: Link, please. . .  Never mind, got it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16553572/revisions

Comment: I edited as well in response to a comment and to replace my comma...

Comment: Personally, I'd go with a semicolon after the word "this". However, I think both edits were fairly useless. They certainly didn't address a "substantial issue".

Answer (score 8):

Your proper recourse is to decline such edits.  You can *[cast a binding vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/102937)* on suggested edits made to your own posts (your sole vote declines the edit, if it hasn't already been accepted by other community members).  You can also roll back bad edits, or edit your changes back into the post.

Comment: Are users that are in the habit of making minor edits flagged or flogged or at least prevented from future editing?

Comment: Yes; there's a review system, and the most egregious abusers are banned from editing for a certain period of time.

Comment: I guess I was mostly irritated to see the word "link" added after the jsFiddle link... I guess I would rather see people allowed to make small edits than add noise and make small edits anyway

Comment: Yep, that would irritate me, too.